# how to set parameters to volley request (GET request )?

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley

I have a volley request with type GET , I want to pass it the number of page and numbers of posts in each page but it doesnt react to my parameter  , here is my request :

(By the way , when I use getParams and getHeaders functions , it wont to anything too)

```
 CustomRequest2 recListReq = new CustomRequest2(Constants.Posts +"?page="+count+"&per_page=1&categories=52" , new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
...
```

and it is my CustomRequest :

```
public class CustomRequest2 extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {
/**
 * Creates a new request.
 * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
 * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
 */
public CustomRequest2(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Request.Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);
}
@Override
protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString =
                new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Should work, what is the error?

Comment: @Stefan it gets the page 1 again and again

Comment: Where is the code where you update your count?

Comment: please switch to retrofit2,volley is too problematic.

Comment: @Stefan before the loadmore called , I debuged the app and saw that count updates every time but the output of the request wont change

Comment: You can debug the url to see if it's the REST service or your request